# SQL for searching for an ambigous field in a second database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm fairly new to SQL and I think the problem here may be down to my poor database structure rather than the SQL code I am using but here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have a front-end form that asks the user to choose a location. It looks something like this (I have simplified it here):

```
<form id="main-form" action="process.php" method="post">
<select id="location_selector" name="location">
<option value="serves_africa">Africa</option>
<option value="serves_aus_nz">Australia & New Zealand</option>
<option value="serves_europe">Europe</option>
<option value="serves_usa">United States</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I then look up the chosen value in my 'companies' database table to return the company name. Lets say the user chose 'Australia & New Zealand'. My companies database table looks something like this:

[image]

And my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT company_name FROM `companies` WHERE `serves_aus_nz` = 1
```

All well and good so far. I now want to return a friendly name for the country selected so on the process.php page I can say something like

**"You selected all companies serving Australia and New Zealand."**

But if I were to take the value passed using something like:

```
echo "You selected all companies serving " . $_POST["location"] . ".";
```

Then I would get:

**"You selected all companies serving serves_aus_nz"**

So, I thought I could create a second database table that converts the unfriendly country names such as 'serves_aus_nz' into friendly country names such as 'Australia & New Zealand". So I created a 'countries' table that looks something like this:

[image]

But now I'm a little lost. I thought I could maybe use an INNER JOIN to do this. So something like:

```
SELECT companies.company_name, countries.friendly_name 
FROM companies 
INNER JOIN countries ON  = companies.serves_aus_nz = countries.unfriendly_name
WHERE `serves_aus_nz` = 1
```

But this doesn't work.

As I say, it feels more like my poor database structure than the SQL but I could well be wrong. So I'd really appreciate either

a) an example SQL query that would work with my existing database tables

or

b) suggestions on how I should better structure my database

Thanks very much in advance for any help or input here.

Comment: Instead of using links to images, you should create DDL and provide sample data if you want to help us to help you:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Tables represent relationships/associations. Here in simplest terms you have "company named COMPANY_NAME serves country [sic] named COUNTRY_NAME". Your 2D boolean-valued grid is just a way to display that table. Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the classic Many-to-Many relationship (answer b):

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab

Comment: Thanks very much for your input - as with many things in programming half the battle is knowing the terminology and how to ask the question. Now I know that I am looking at a many-many relationship issue I expect I'll be able to find lots of help online. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a many to many relationship.
You might solve your current problem like this example

```
SELECT c.company_name, 
       case when c.serves_africa = 0 then null 
            else (select ct.friendly_name from countries ct where ct.unfriendly_name = 'serves_africa')
       end as Africa,

       case when c.serves_aus_nz = 0 then null 
            else (select ct.friendly_name from countries ct where ct.unfriendly_name = 'serves_aus_nz')
       end as AusNz,

       case when c.serves_europe = 0 then null 
            else (select ct.friendly_name from countries ct where ct.unfriendly_name = 'serves_europe')
       end as Europe,

       case when c.serves_usa = 0 then null 
            else (select ct.friendly_name from countries ct where ct.unfriendly_name = 'serves_usa')
       end as Usa

FROM   companies c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Will try this out this afternoon and let you know if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right that the schema of your database is making this hard. If you properly normalise the database then you would be able to use a join as you won't have a many-to-many relationship anymore. I also have two 'hacky' solutions:

- You know the unfriendly name when you make your original SQL query so you could just send two queries:

  - `SELECT company_name FROM companies WHERE serves_aus_nz = 1`
  - `SELECT friendly_name FROM countries WHERE unfriendly_name = 'serves_aus_nz'`
- You could take the problem out of the database and into the UI.

  - The User input a choice at some point so you can can just have a table within your code that converts the user's input into the nice name.

Comment: Great thank you. I will take the hacks for now and go away and read about proper database relationship construction.